# How to Prove Minimum modulus principle without using Maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

As we know that we can prove minimum modulus principle using maximum modulus principle but I want to prove it without using maximum modulus principle.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?